# Finite dimensional subspace of a vector space

Tags: analysis

I know that every subspace of a finite dimensional vector space are closed. Is that true that every finite subspace of a vector space (of any dimension) are closed? Thank you!

Comment: Vector sapces do not come with a topology so the concept of closed sets does no exist in general.

Comment: And if you consider the topology associated to a scalar product?

Comment: Finite dimensional subspaces of an inner product space are always closed. This is a basic result in FA. You can find a proof in Rudin's FA.